# Unable to open Spyder (from Anaconda3)

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda3

I have encountered an error opening Spyder.

At the end of the command opening Spyder

```
spyder --new-instance
```

it shows a line: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 49: invalid start byte`

And I also run a line: `pip check`
which gave the results:

```
conda-repo-cli 1.0.27 has requirement clyent==1.2.1, but you have clyent 1.2.2.
conda-repo-cli 1.0.27 has requirement nbformat==5.4.0, but you have nbformat 5.7.0.
```

I would really appreciate it if someone who has also encountered this before could grant some insights to me.

As I navigated in the internet, I tried a solution to update gensim:

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

And the updates have completed to gensim-4.3.1. (previous 4.3.0)